# 12.10 restore default theme

Tags: themes, default, restore

I've been playing with different themes on my fresh 12.10 and it seems that I deleted default, if you can call it that, theme files from .themes. Now it doesn't show some icons like terminal's and gedit's. Is there a way to completely restore it? Are there any packages to install?

Comment: How did you install themes? The default theme is not in the .themes folder in your home folder. Try opening System settings, Appearance and choose the Ambiance theme there.

Comment: If you cant find them Ambiance and Radiance themes are light themes ---  sudo apt-get install light-themes  -- or use the software center and search for themes

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal Ctrl+Alt+T and run following command:

**Reset Icon Pack**

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme ''`

**Reset Theme**

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme ''`
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme ''`
`gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/metacity/general/theme ''`

**Reset Launcher**

`gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites`

**Reset Panel**

`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"`

After running all of this commands, logout and log back in.